# How to fix Deprecated: Function zip_open() is deprecated in SpreadsheetReader.php

Tags: php

I try to upload excel to MySQL DB using PHP 8.1.0

- CSV format excel is working fine
- XLSX format excel is NOT working

showing below deprecated warning while importing excel

> Deprecated: Function zip_open() is deprecated in
> C:\MAMP\htdocs\deepu\include\dragan\library\SpreadsheetReader.php

**Here is my full code:**
https://coding-zon.blogspot.com/2022/04/import-excel-file-into-mysql-in-php.html

**Video:**
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ON4GkIc6two

**Here is PHP lib code**
https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader

Comment: It says in the PHP doc for that function "8.0.0: This function is deprecated in favour of the Object API, see ZipArchive::open().". It looks as if the author of that library needs to update their code to use the new method.

Answer (score 0):

The `zip_open` function is deprecated since PHP 8 in favor of `ZipArchive::open()`. For now it works, but it will be removed in future versions of PHP.

The https://github.com/nuovo/spreadsheet-reader library is actually 7 years old and not fully compatible with PHP 8.0. The best option here is to look for a replacement (it has a lot of forks, maybe someone is maintaining it on their own).

You could also create your own fork and use `ZipArchive::open()` there. But you have no guarantee the rest of the library will work properly in modern PHP.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet
It works very well for me and will allow you to extract your spreadsheets very easily!
Most of all, it is maintained and fully PHP 8 compatible.